# How to insert data into a db link table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I am working on a `sql server` script in order to write to an `oracle` table.

I wrote a procedure that gets my data and stores it into a temporary table. Now, I'm not sure what to do to insert that data into a table on my dblink to oracle db. I tried a couple things, but by `dblink_table` is not recognized as an object.

```
INSERT INTO dblink_table@dblink_name AS SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

I've tested my dblink connection and it works fine

Comment: can you select from dblinktable?  Does the Oracle user have insert on that table? Did you issue a commit  (SQL Server issues an implicit commit but for a link it is worth a try? )  What was the error message?

Comment: Yes i can select and no I did not commit since insert is failing

Comment: what is the error you're getting from the insert? also, what is the structure of either table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax you used (actually, *posted*) looks wrong; `as` seems to be superfluous.

```
INSERT INTO dblink_table@dblink_name SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

Though, I prefer & I'd suggest you to always mention all columns involved, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO dblink_table@dblink_name
  (id, name, job, sal)
  SELECT id, name, job sal
  FROM #temp;
```

Comment: I got my insert to "work" by changing the syntax; I now have `INSERT INTO dblink_name..dblink_schema.dblink_table SELECT * FROM #temp`. However I'm getting datatype errors but that's another quest !

Comment: Great; I'm glad you made it. Thank you for letting us know.

Comment: However, I tried your syntax and it worked too, so I'll accept your answer.